Cookies are not being set in browser/gets deleted after reload
let me describe the full scenario:
Frontend is running on https://front.exampleone.com, backend is running on https://api.exampletwo.com. Notice both of them are running on different TLD.
When from frontend user trying to login to backend login route with email and password, the backend is setting cookie in the response header. Like this:
Set-Cookie: access=access_token_value; expires=Mon, 05 Aug 2024 12:33:31 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=432000; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure
Set-Cookie: refresh=refresh_token_value; expires=Thu, 01 Aug 2024 12:33:31 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=86400; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure

Also, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials and access-control-allow-origin is also set on request header.

Here I have set SameSite=None because the Domain is different. (Let me know if this is correct)
If I see the cookie tab in browser dev tool, I can see that the cookie is there:

But if Reload the frontend page, I can see that the cookie is removed.

Although, the cookie is removed I can make request to private routes from frontend, which has the cookie information attached to the request header and the api is working as expected:

I have found these behaviour in Chrome, Edge and Brave browser. But for Safari, the cookies are not being set at all. And the subsequent api request is giving me 401 status since no cookie are being sent with the request header.
Why is this happening? Help me fix this issue. I am using Django, Django Rest Framework for backend and React, axios for frontend.
Yes, I have set withCredentials: true to axios. I have tried with fetch as well. The result is the same.
Remember, this thing is happening only if I use different domain for frontend and backend. If I use the same domain then everything is working as expected. (Tested in localhost)
For example,

(Frontend: http://localhost:3000, backend: http://localhost:8000) --> This works as expected
(Frontend: http://localhost:3000, backend: http://127.0.0.1:8000) --> This does not work

